# Getting server error 404 on using Simple Rest Client

Tags: spring, rest

I'm building a project using Spring MVC3.1,in my project I'm implementing the use of restful resources.for this purpose I have downloaded the "Simple Rest Client" extension of Google Chrome Web Browser.But whenever I'm trying to send data from client side I'm getting the error
"404 Not Found".below is my controller class named "BookRestController.java"

```
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/services")
   public class BookRestController {

   private InBookService inBookService;

   public InBookService getInBookService() {
    return inBookService;
  }

  @Autowired
  public void setInBookService(InBookService inBookService) {
      this.inBookService = inBookService;
   }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/book", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/xml,application/json")
   public @ResponseBody String addUserBook(@RequestBody UserBook userBook) {
    inBookService.saveBook(userBook);
    return "true";
  }
 }
```

Can anyone give me any solution for this?????????
Here is my web.xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>    
</welcome-file-list>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>bsm</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>bsm</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/bsm-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>com.edifixio.bsm.resource.Label</param-value>
   </context-param>
</web-app>
```

and my servlet spring servlet configuration are as follows named:bsm-servlet.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.edifixio.bsm"/>

<bean class="com.edifixio.bsm.validator.BookValidator"/>
<bean class="com.edifixio.bsm.validator.SystemUserValidator"/> 

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/"
      p:suffix=".jsp"/>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/data_resources/jdbc_info.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
      p:driverClassName="${JDBC_DRIVERCLASS_NAME}"
      p:url="${JDBC_URL}" p:username="${JDBC_USER_NAME}"
      p:password="${JDBC_PASSWORD}"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>/WEB-INF/data_resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${JDBC_DIALECT}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionInterceptor" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

and I'm invoking the following url from Simple Rest Client:

```
 http://localhost:8087/BookShopMaintanance-war/services/book
```

can anyone give me any suitable solution to this??????

Comment: What does the servlet mapping look like? Which url are you trying to acccess?

Comment: put web.xml file and other mapping config and url you are putting in browser to test

Comment: Are you providing your json or xml in the body of your request? Can you post it too? Maybe your json or xml is not well formed and it is not able to map it to the RequestBody of your method that should be a UserBook. Are you using Jackson or any other for deserializing Json and JAXB or any other for deserializing XML?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are invoking the url < host>/< context>/< servlet_maping>/services/book. Are you using POST as method and  including the header "Accept=application/xml,application/json" in your request?.

Other common problem is that the controller maybe not including in the .

In any case put the log level of Spring-mvc to debug it should show you enought info to resolve the problem.

Comment: I am using the url:http://localhost:8087/BookShopMaintanance-war/services/book.  what do you meant by <context>/<servlet-mapping>???I have given the url here whcih I am putting in the browser.is it correct???

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the previous response, try an OPTIONS request to the same url and see what does it returns.

It could be that the problem is related to the fact that you don't specify what the method produces.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/book", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
```